# filter the post based on start and end date using date picker in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, scope, datepicker

I have the post index page which displays all the posts.In that page i need to set up a filter using datepicker which provides start and end date.When user click on search button it sends a get method request to the controller with start date and end date as parameters.I need to use a scope method in the post model for filtering the post.As a newbie for rails I don't know how to proceed after creating the html view.Please help me.

```
Index.html.erb
```

```html
<div class="container" >

  <% if params[:topic_id].present? %>
    <h2 align="center"><span class="em-text"><%= @topic.topicname %> Posts</span></h2><hr>
    <%= link_to "New Post", new_topic_post_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary new_one' ,remote: true%> <br><br><br>
  <% else %>
    <h2 align="center"><span class="em-text">All Posts</span></h2><hr>
  <% end %>
  <div>
    <input type="date" id="start_date">
    <input type="date" id="end_date">
  </div>

<div class="post_div">
  <%= render @posts %>
</div>
  <%= will_paginate @posts, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
</div>
```

Post partial which is render

```html
  <div class="well">

    <% if ReadStatus.where(" user_id = ? AND post_id = ?",current_user.id,post.id).blank? %>
      <p style="color:Tomato;",class="read_text">Unread!!</p>
    <%end %>

    <h4><b><%= post.title  %> (<%= post.topic.topicname %>)</b></h4>
    <p><%= post.body %></p>

    <div>

      <%= image_tag post.image.url(:thumb) %>

    </div>

    <%= "Average Rating: "  %>
    <%=post.ratings.average(:rate).to_f.round(1)%>
    <br>
    <%= link_to "comments",topic_post_path(topic_id:post.topic_id, id:post.id) %>
    <%=post.comments.count%>
    <%= link_to "View Post", topic_post_path(topic_id:post.topic_id, id:post.id ), :class => 'btn btn-default btn1'%>
    <% if can? :update, post %>
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_topic_post_path(topic_id:post.topic_id, id:post.id), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <% end %>
    <% if can? :destroy, post %>
      <%= link_to "Delete", [post.topic, post], method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, :class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
    <% end %>

  </div>
```

Post controller index action:

```
  def index
 @posts=Post.all
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few assumptions I have made for answering you question. In case of any changes, please let me know and I will modify my answer accordingly.

Assumptions:

- You have a button to send the start date and end date as search params.
- The search request is being sent as a HTML request.
- Filter is based on the Post's created time.
- You are using Rails 5+

You can find my solution below:

Replace

```
<input type="date" id="start_date">
<input type="date" id="end_date">
```

with

```
<%= form_tag posts_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'start_date', params[:start_date], placeholder: "Enter Start Date" %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'end_date', params[:end_date], placeholder: "Enter End Date" %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

Add the following code to your Posts controller:

```
before_action :can_search, only: %i(index)

def index
  @posts = @can_search ? Post.where(created_at: Time.parse(params[:start_date])..Time.parse(params[:end_date]))
end

private

def can_search
  @can_search = false
  return unless (params[:start_date].present? && params[:end_date].present?)
  @can_search = (Time.parse(params[:start_date]) rescue nil).present? && (Time.parse(params[:end_date]) rescue nil).present?
  if @can_search
    @can_search = Time.parse(params[:start_date]) < Time.parse(params[:end_date]
  end
end
```

The form in view lets you send start and end dates as `params` to your index action.

The `before_action` method will validate if both start and end dates are passed and are valid dates.

If valid start and end dates are passed, you can fetch Posts within the time frame. Otherwise all Posts are fetched.

Hope this helped you.

Comment: I need to use datepicker for that we can use date_field_tag.

Comment: May i know what is the use of rescue here

Comment: To check if the dates passed are valid. Otherwise it'll throw an exception.

Comment: For using a datepicker, you can use this package https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: I got the answer

Comment: To check if the dates passed are valid. Otherwise it'll throw an exception. Just a a fail safe